# How to modify a key's value in a JSON file from command line

Tags: json, shell, command-line

Is it possible to change the `value` of a `key` in a JSON file from command line?

e.g., in package.json:

Change

```
{
    ...
    ...
    "something": "something",
    "name": "idan" 
    ...
}
```

To

```
{
    ...
    ...
    "something": "something",
    "name": "adar" 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

One way to achieve it is by using the ["json" npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json), e.g.:

```
json -I -f package.json -e "this.name='adar'"
```

Another way is by using the [jq CLI](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), e.g.:

```
mv package.json temp.json
jq -r '.name |= "adar"' temp.json > package.json
rm temp.json
```

Comment: Why the two moves?

Comment: The move and the redirect are a good idea because the alternative is to redirect into the original file, and if there's an error parsing the file with jq, you will loose the original file.

Comment: jq -r '.name |= "adar"'  package.json | sponge package.json
"sponge" comes in the "moreutils" package which must be installed first.

Comment: How can I replace the value if the key name is with a dot? For example `user.password`?

Answer (score 2):

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
$ xidel -s --in-place package.json -e '($json).name:="adar"'
```

```
$ xidel -s --in-place package.json -e 'map:put($json,"name","adar")'
```

```
$ xidel -s --in-place package.json -e 'map:merge(($json,{"name":"adar"}),{"duplicates":"use-last"})'
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [`sde`](https://github.com/dvershinin/sde) CLI utility, you can

```sh
sde name adar package.json
```

Answer (score -7):

The anoter way is to open the file itself in terminal :

```
pico filename.json
```

edit it then save then exit.

check if correct changes were made:

```
cat filename.json
```

Comment: Dude, he meant programmatically. Of course you could manually edit the file.