# How to change VS Code settings from terminal (bash)

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal, settings

For example I want to force VS Code to always add an empty line at the end of all files on save.

I have to:

1. Open VS Code
2. Go to preferences
3. Search for `Insert Finale Newline`
4. Check it

Can I use bash to set this an other settings?

The reason I'm asking for this, is that we want to create a `configure-vs-code.sh` script that we can run on any VS Code to configure it as we want.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should use the setting.json file, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909052/16982590) is an answer to find it.
2. And to be able to edit it, you can use the [json npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43292244/16982590).
3. Finally it should look something like this:

**setting.json**

```json
{
    "keys":
    {
        "insert_finale_newline": false
    }
}
```

**configure-vs-code.sh**

```
json -I -f $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json -e "this.keys.insert_finale_newline=true"
```