# Using Bash to edit VS Code Settings

Tags: json, linux, bash, visual-studio-code, npm

I am trying to use the npm `package.json` to edit the VS Code settings from a bash script. I found [How to change VS Code settings from terminal (bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73867739/how-to-change-vs-code-settings-from-terminal-bash) which has helped me to almost achieve what I wanted.

I am trying to change the color theme of the workbench. My `settings.json` currently looks like this and is located under `HOME/.config/Code/User/` (Linux):

```json
{
   "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern"
}
```

My bash script looks as follows:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/bash

json -I -f $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json -e 'this.workbench.colorTheme="Default Dark Modern"'
```

and I get the following error:

```
undefined:3
this.workbench.colorTheme="Default Dark Modern"
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'colorTheme')
    at Object.eval (eval at main (/usr/lib/node_modules/json/lib/json.js:1365:27), <anonymous>:3:26)
    at parseChunk (/usr/lib/node_modules/json/lib/json.js:1569:29)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/json/lib/json.js:1426:13
    at getInput (/usr/lib/node_modules/json/lib/json.js:738:17)
    at main (/usr/lib/node_modules/json/lib/json.js:1396:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/json/lib/json.js:1764:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:12)

Node.js v21.7.1
```

I think it has something to do with that the key "workbench.colorTheme" is separated by a dot, but I unfortunately cannot find anything to fix this issue. I have already tried switching out the " " with ' ' and accessing the key in different ways, for example `this[workbench.colorTheme]` or `this.workbench[colorTheme]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brackets and quotes are needed.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

json -I -f $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json -e 'this["workbench.colorTheme"]="Default Dark Modern"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `json` NPM package, but [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) is much more common tool that is purpose-built for command-line JSON manipulation.
If you want to edit this JSON inline, then you want to pipe the [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) result to [`sponge`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/sponge.1.html)

Example:

```
jq '.["workbench.colorTheme"] |= "My New Theme"' /tmp/foo.json | sponge /tmp/foo.json
```

For Example:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.json
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern"
}
$ jq '.["workbench.colorTheme"] |= "My New Theme"' /tmp/foo.json | sponge /tmp/foo.json
$ cat /tmp/foo.json
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "My New Theme"
}
```

#### Script

A bash going this route might take your desired theme in as the first argument for example

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Don't overwrite the settings.json file if anything fails
set -eo pipefail

# Default and quote whatever comes in as the argument
theme="$(jq -R . <<<"${1:-Default Dark Modern}")"

file="$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json"
jq ".[\"workbench.colorTheme\"] |= $theme" "$file"| sponge "$file"
```

**Usage**

```
$ script.sh 'My new theme "even with quotes"'
```

Comment: I have not tried to implement this as another answer regarding the npm json package has already solved the problem. Thank you!